# How to determine the heap size, stack size of a running process for FreeBSD

Tags: stack, heap-memory, daemon, freebsd

How to determine the current heap size, stack size of a running process in FreeBSD, if I have no access to valgrind and even /proc/pid/map also does not have any heap or stack entry.

Comment: probably this could help `procstat` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46236181/1135424

Comment: @nbari I dont find any heap related info

Comment: Do you really have anything at all in /proc? FreeBSD does not use that itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install Valgrind, or else download a built it from source. If you can do that, use Massif.

HeapTrack is another heap profiler, considerably faster than Massif but it won't work if you are using exotic allocation techniques.

Lastly, `pmap -x` will give you an ASCII snapshot of the memory map of a running exe.